# Trying to build library and getting the following warning: warning: type of bit-field ‘type’ is a GCC extension [-Wpedantic] uint8_t type:1;

Tags: c, shell, gcc, travis-ci, gnu

I am trying to build sysrepo library https://github.com/sysrepo/sysrepo as a dependency on travis ci and am getting an issue with bit fields. I do not get this issue when I do an install on an ubuntu vm in either 14.04 or 16.04 and am quite confused why it appears when using travis ci. My build script that installs everything is below:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
#this script installs sysrepo and all of its dependencies.
INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR=$HOME/local
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR/lib/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
export CC=gcc

sudo apt-get update -qq
sudo apt-get install -y cmake libev-dev libavl-dev
sudo apt-get install -y build-essential
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR/lib

GODIR=$PWD
cd $HOME

if [ ! -d "$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR/lib" ]; then

  # libyang
  git clone https://github.com/CESNET/libyang.git
  cd libyang ; mkdir build ; cd build
  cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR  -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug -DENABLE_BUILD_TESTS=OFF ..
  make -j2 && sudo make install
  cd ../..

  # protobuf
  git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf.git
  cd protobuf
  ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR
  sudo make -j2
  sudo make install
  cd ..

  # protobuf-c
  git clone https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c.git
  cd protobuf-c
  ./autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR
  sudo make -j2
  sudo make install
  cd ..

else
    echo "Using cached libraries from $INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR"
fi

echo "$INSTALL_PREFIX_DIR/lib" | sudo tee /etc/ld.so.conf.d/sysrepolibs.conf
sudo ldconfig

#sysrepo
git clone https://github.com/sysrepo/sysrepo.git
cd sysrepo
mkdir build ; cd build ;
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=$HOME/local ..
make
sudo make install
cd ../..

sudo ldconfig

#start sysrepo
sudo sysrepod -d -l4 &> sysrepod.log &

cd $GODIR
```

This is called in a before_script on travis and everything works except I get these warnings:

```
 [  3%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/COMMON.dir/common/sysrepo.pb-c.c.o
    [  5%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/COMMON.dir/common/sr_common.c.o
    In file included from /home/travis/local/include/libyang/libyang.h:20:0,
                     from /home/travis/sysrepo/src/common/sr_utils.h:36,
                     from /home/travis/sysrepo/src/common/sr_common.h:44,
                     from /home/travis/sysrepo/src/common/sr_common.c:28:
    /home/travis/local/include/libyang/tree_schema.h:241:5: warning: type of bit-field ‘type’ is a GCC extension [-Wpedantic]
         uint8_t type:1;                  /**< 0 - structure type used to distinguish structure from ::lys_submodule */
         ^
    /home/travis/local/include/libyang/tree_schema.h:242:5: warning: type of bit-field ‘version’ is a GCC extension [-Wpedantic]
         uint8_t version:4;               /**< yang-version:
         ^
    /home/travis/local/include/libyang/tree_schema.h:246:5: warning: type of bit-field ‘deviated’ is a GCC extension [-Wpedantic]
         uint8_t deviated:2;
```

I am no expert at building C projects but any help would be greatly appreciated?

Comment: The only question is, do you care about these being gcc extensions? (In case you do not know what that means: this code will not compile with another compiler.)

Comment: The code might lack some `#include <stdint.h>`

Comment: If you think that any answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it (the green checkmark to the left of the answer). This will indicate to the community that the question has been answered and will give some reputation to you and the answerer.

Answer (score 4):

C supports only int, unsigned int, and _Bool as types for bit-fields. Other types are implementation defined.

Using the flag -Wpedantic the compiler will follow the standard strictly and will try to warn you if you use certain implementation-defined features or extensions.

Remove the flag -Wpedantic.

Comment: I cannot change the flag it is set in the cmake file of library I am dependent on. What I cant understand is why the same code does not fire this warning on a different machine.

Comment: @Westy10101 Maybe a different gcc version? If you can't change anything then you're gonna have to ignore the warnings it seems.

Comment: I checked the gcc versions and they seem to match. I am completely lost. It doesnt actually cause me any issues its just one of those things I would rather not be there. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Bit fields are signed integers, unsigned integers, or bools as per the standard

C11 6.7.2.1 - Secton 5

> A bit-ﬁeld shall have a type that is a qualiﬁed or unqualiﬁed version of _Bool, signed int, unsigned int, or some other implementation-deﬁned type. It is implementation-deﬁned whether atomic types are permitted.